# jquery mobile inconsistent transition effects between iOS and Android

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I've been working with the jQuery Mobile 1.0 release and been testing a few pages I've set up using the default slideIn transition. I have tested these pages on iOS4 + 5 and Android 2.3.3.
iOS handles the effects well but Android i have to say is terrible, sometime the slideIn transition occurs before jumping back to the previous page, sometimes there is no transition just a jump, sometimes I get a plain grey page, no matter what the pages always flicker. Also the header, although not fixed seems to jump down the page on scroll. Has anyone else experienced these kind of problems? If so can you share any tips / advice / suggestions on how to enhance the Android experience (if that's possible).

I am using the following test page http://kylehouston.com/testing/sub-testing/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I ran into the same issues, something that JQM is working to solve: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/455

In the meantime, I found disabling the animations (or changing into for example pop ones) reduces somehow the issue for Android mobiles (and tablets!).

Comment: here's the jqm documentation: [JQM Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-transitions.html). Note that even there the Android issues are mentioned...